# Como criar um regex em Python para pegar um texto específico?

Tags: python, regex

Por exemplo, quero pegar a string abaixo:

> TEXTO ACIMA
>
> **EXMO. SR. DR. JUÍZ DE DIREITO
>   DO JUIZADO ESPECIAL
>   CÍVEL DA COMARCA DA CAPITAL**
>
> TEXTO ABAIXO

A palavra **EXMO.** pode eventualmente ser substituída por **EXCELENTISSIMO** e a palavra **JUIZADO** por **VARA**.

Tentei usar a regex abaixo, mas não consegui muita coisa:

```
re.findall(r'((?:exmo|excelentissimo))', text, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso proceder para conseguir pegar esse pedaço de string por completo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, não precisa de dois pares de parênteses seguidos.

Quando há parênteses, eles formam um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). Ou seja, o que está dentro deles estará disponível em um [grupo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group), caso a regex encontre um *match*. Esse é o comportamento padrão dos parênteses.

Mas quando você não quer capturar um grupo, e apenas agrupar sub-expressões, usa-se a sintaxe `(?:`, que define um [grupo de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap). Basicamente, isso diz que o par de parênteses não deve criar um grupo, caso a regex encontre um *match*.

Por isso fazer `((?:...))` é meio estranho. É um grupo de não-captura dentro de um grupo de captura, ou seja, você disse que quer capturar algo, e esse algo é "uma coisa que não quero capturar". Contraditório e desnecessário, então a primeira coisa é eliminar isso (e dependendo do caso, escolher apenas um deles, caso seja preciso).

De qualquer forma, o que está dentro dos parênteses é `exmo|excelentissimo`, que significa "a string `exmo` **ou** a string `excelentissimo`". Esta regex pega somente este trecho, ignorando o restante da string.

Para pegar a linha toda, basta usar uma regex que pegue todo o texto:

```
import re

text = """
TEXTO ACIMA

EXMO. SR. DR. JUÍZ DE DIREITO DO JUIZADO ESPECIAL CÍVEL DA COMARCA DA CAPITAL

TEXTO ABAIXO

EXCELENTISSIMO. SR. DR. JUÍZ DE DIREITO DA VARA ESPECIAL CÍVEL DA COMARCA DA CAPITAL

MAIS TEXTO"""

results = re.findall(r'^(?:EXMO|EXCELENTISSIMO)\. SR\. DR\. JUÍZ DE DIREITO (?:DO JUIZADO|DA VARA) ESPECIAL CÍVEL DA COMARCA DA CAPITAL$',
                     text, re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

for result in results:
    print(result)
```

Repare que usei `(?:EXMO|EXCELENTISSIMO)` e `(?:DO JUIZADO|DA VARA)` para as partes que podem ser uma coisa ou outra. Eu usei grupos de não-captura - repare na sintaxe `(?:` - pois [segundo a documentação de `findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall), quando há grupos de captura na regex, somente os grupos são retornados. Mas como você quer a string inteira, eu usei grupos de não-captura.

Já o restante do texto, como não muda, pode ser exatamente o que você quer ("SR. DR. JUIZ etc"). A única exceção é o ponto, já que em regex ele possui significado especial (significa ["qualquer caractere"](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)), então ele deve ser escapado e escrito como `\.`.

Outro detalhe são os [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$`, que normalmente significam o início e fim da string. Mas graças à [flag `MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE), eles também são interpretados como o início e fim de uma linha. Com isso você garante que a linha contém somente o que está especificado na regex.

O código acima imprime:

```
EXMO. SR. DR. JUÍZ DE DIREITO DO JUIZADO ESPECIAL CÍVEL DA COMARCA DA CAPITAL
EXCELENTISSIMO. SR. DR. JUÍZ DE DIREITO DA VARA ESPECIAL CÍVEL DA COMARCA DA CAPITAL
```

---

Como você usou a [flag `IGNORECASE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE), a regex também pegará trechos com letras minúsculas ("exmo. sr. dr. etc...") e até mesmo maiúsculas e minúsculas misturadas ("eXMo. sR. Dr ..."). Se quiser que ela pegue somente letras maiúsculas, remova esta flag (mas não se esqueça de manter o `MULTILINE`):

```
results = re.findall(r'^(?:EXMO|EXCELENTISSIMO)\. SR\. DR\. JUÍZ DE DIREITO (?:DO JUIZADO|DA VARA) ESPECIAL CÍVEL DA COMARCA DA CAPITAL$',
                     text, re.MULTILINE)
```

---

Quando fui editar sua pergunta, vi que o texto estava ocupando 3 linhas:

```
EXMO. SR. DR. JUÍZ DE DIREITO
DO JUIZADO ESPECIAL
CÍVEL DA COMARCA DA CAPITAL
```

Não sei se é assim mesmo ou se deveria estar tudo em uma linha. Em todo caso, podemos trocar o espaço depois de "DIREITO" e "ESPECIAL" por `\s`, que considera tanto o espaço quando a quebra de linha:

```
results = re.findall(r'^(?:EXMO|EXCELENTISSIMO)\. SR\. DR\. JUÍZ DE DIREITO\s(?:DO JUIZADO|DA VARA) ESPECIAL\sCÍVEL DA COMARCA DA CAPITAL$',
                     text, re.MULTILINE)
```

Se quiser, também pode usar `[ \n]` (um espaço ou `\n` - repare que há um espaço depois do `[`), já que `\s` também considera outros caracteres, como o <kbd>TAB</kbd> e outros mencionados na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

Comment: Entendi, meu amigo. Grato pelas explicações. Tenho mais uma dúvida: há casos em que aparece ESPECIAL CIVEL e apenas CIVEL. Como faço para esses casos?

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola Se "ESPECIAL" é opcional, faça `(?: ESPECIAL)? CÍVEL` (atenção para o espaço antes do "ESPECIAL"). O `?` depois do parênteses torna todo o conteúdo entre parênteses opcional.

Comment: (?: ESPECIAL)? não funcionou, porém ?(?: ESPECIAL)?, com um primeiro '?' à frente. Grato!

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola Talvez vc tenha colocado um espaço a mais (ou algum outro detalhe), pois comigo funcionou: https://ideone.com/UubJ61

Comment: Blz, vou averiguar. Agradeço mais uma vez pelos detalhe. Ajudaram muito.

Comment: apareceu outra dúvida. Caso eu queira capturar apenas até a palavra CIVEL, sendo que após essa palavra pode aparecer outras coisas, como posso fazer? Tipo "EXMO. SR. DR. JUÍZ DE DIREITO DO JUIZADO ESPECIAL CÍVEL DA COMARCA DA CAPITAL" quero pegar até "EXMO. SR. DR. JUÍZ DE DIREITO DO JUIZADO ESPECIAL CÍVEL".

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola É só tirar a parte que  não interessa: https://ideone.com/s1i7IJ

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola Como daqui a pouco vou desligar o computador, eu sugiro que, caso surjam dúvidas diferentes, vc [**faça outra pergunta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), pois aí vc não fica dependendo somente de mim (já que uma nova pergunta fica mais visível para qualquer um responder, pois ela aparece na página principal, diferente dos comentários, que só aparecem aqui) :-) Digo isso também pq a ideia do site é ter um problema específico por pergunta, e isso ajuda a manter o site organizado (não interprete isso como "preguiça de ajudar" da minha parte) :-)

Comment: Tranquilo, tudo certo. Obrigado mais uma vez!